# ELECTRUM STYLE WORD LIST FAILED VERIFICATION

Tags: mnemonic-seed

I am having a problem gaining access to monero wallet via ledger x
It will not accept the password so I have tried to restore from seed and the get this message ELECTRUM STYLE WORD LIST FAILED VERIFICATION any help greatly appreciated